# What would be the Jewish version of the 12 steps

Tags: jewish-books

In dealing with issues.
Are there any seforim in English or hebrew that deal with psychological issues in a systematic way based on torah sources.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1937887952

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Dr. Abraham J. Twerski zt"l walks through each of the 12 steps [here](https://www.torahweb.org/torah/special/2010/dtwe_12steps.html) and shows how they work with, and likely stem from, Jewish sources.

> It may be argued that the first of the 12-step programs, Alcoholics
> Anonymous, was the outgrowth of a Christian group. This is true.
> However, as we shall see, the content of the 12-step programs is not
> only compatible with Torah, but actually seems to have been adopted
> from Torah sources. I cannot understand how the founder of AA, Bill
> Wilson, had access to concepts that we find in the Talmud and the
> mussar writings. The fact that they were adopted by a Christian group
> hardly disqualifies them, just as the kedusha in the amidah was not
> disqualified by its adoption into the Lord's Prayer.

Although works from Rabbi Twerski, like *Self-Improvement? I'm Jewish* and *Stepping Out of the Abyss: A Jewish Guide to the 12 Steps*, which Deuteronomy shared in a comment, are fantastic self-help works to work through psychological struggles, it may be worth reaching out to a trusted rabbi or psychotherapist. Someone knowledgeable of your specific circumstances can provide a better tailored answer to what specific book would help in your situation.